# CSS fade-in / ease effect on page load

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I'm looking for the best way to ease-in/fade elements on page load.

I really like how it looks on http://alpha.musicinfo.fi/ when you do a search and the contents kinda slide/fade in.

was wondering how they are achieving it as it's working pretty slick across browsers and mobile.

Thanks!

Comment: Please, edit your question and add a code of what you tried.

Comment: I haven't started coding it yet, looking for best approach advice ;-)

Comment: set CSS to `display:none;` than with with jQuery: `$('#slider').fadeTo(900, 1);` and all that on window.load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the simplest animation, you'll want to use CSS3 transitions, [which are supported on everything except opera mobile](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions).

```
transition: top 0.2s ease-in, opacity 0.2s ease-in
-webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease-in, opacity 0.2s ease-in
opacity: 0.0;
position: relative;
top: 20px;
```

And then with javascript or jQuery you can set the new state on load.

```
$('#element').css({opacity: 1.0, top: '0px'})
```

But for the most flexibility and control, you'll want to use jQuery's `.animate()` function.  Then you can do something like 
`$('#element').animate({
opacity: '1.0',
top: '0px'
}, 200)`

Have the default CSS set to `opacity: 0; top: 20px; position: relative;`

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 animation is probably the easiest and way to accomplish this, but it is not very well supported.  I think your most realistic option, balancing ease of implementation and browser support, would be using the jQuery's `.fadeIn()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method using jQuery's `addClass` function.

The example is kind of ugly, but it you get the idea.  Also to smooth things out use CSS3 transitions like `transition` etc.

Also add more than one class to change to collapse the box.
This is just another method, maybe not the best, but still another way.

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GrsXx/